# Containing image into specific block in React-Native

Tags: css, react-native

I'm trying to contain this image to one of the blocks in this card, but it doesn't matter what I do, it keeps escaping it's boundaries. I've to put a maximum size to the container `card`, or the container `image` in the Stylesheets, or you name it.

What I'm looking for is the image to be rescaled to the block above the title `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet` instead of it moving all the way to the screen.

Here's what I have, this block is called inside a main container in the App.js, which has only a `flex: 1` set in there. This is the Card.js class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

let WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window');

class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View style = { styles.card } >
                <View style = { styles.inner } >
                    <View style = { styles.image }>
                        <Image source = { require('./nbc.jpg') } />
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <Text style = { styles.title }> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <Text style = { styles.excerpt }>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                        Nunc finibus sapien a aliquet iaculis. Proin tempor magna at purus sodales, et ullamcorper
                        eros viverra. Suspendisse potenti.</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style = { styles.footer }>
                        <View style = { styles.favorite }>
                            <Text style = { styles.favorite }> Favorite </Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style = { styles.bookmark }>
                            <Text style = { styles.bookmarks }> Bookmarks </Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style = { styles.share }>
                            <Text style = { styles.share }> Share </Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    card: {
        backgroundColor: "#f9f9f9",
        flex: 1,
    },
    inner: {
        backgroundColor: "#001F54",
    },
    image: {
        flex: 1,
        height: undefined,
        width: undefined,
        maxHeight: 200,
        resizeMode: "contain",
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 20,
        color: "#FEFCFB",
        textAlign: "center",
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 5,
        backgroundColor: "#1282A2"
    },
    excerpt: {
        fontSize: 16,
        color: "#FEFCFB",
        paddingTop: 5,
        paddingRight: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        paddingLeft: 5
    },
    footer: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        height: 35,
        backgroundColor: "#1282A2",
        paddingTop: 10
    },
    favorite: {
        flex: 1,
        color: "#FEFCFB",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    bookmarks: {
        flex: 1,
        color: "#FEFCFB",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    share: {
        flex: 1,
        color: "#FEFCFB",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
    }
});

export default Card;

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Card', () => Card);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `flex:1` from your styles and restyle it to your liking. Using `flex:1` makes the component take up all available space in its parent.

An example of manually sizing the parent would be

```
image: {
    width: '90%',
    height: '90%',
}
```

Comment: I removed all of the `flex: 1`, but it was still escaping the size of the View for the image, although not the size of the Card, so I moved the Image view from inside the inner block and now it's contained there, but the image still won't rescale at all. I'm failing to find ways to rescale it without setting a size manually. Do you know how I can rescale it contained to that rectangle on my example above? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the resizeMode attribute for Image components? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image

Comment: Yup. `cover` and `contain` didn't change a thing. The only thing that changes something is `maxHeight`, I've tried to use `maxWidth` with `Dimensions`, but it doesn't accept it.

Comment: There's not much you can do if you don't want any manual sizing done at all. I usually manually size the parent container, then put flex:1 on the Image component

Comment: But how do you deal with different types of screens?

Comment: By using percentages.

Comment: Eh? That's the first thing I've tried, I searched into it, but every time, say, I used `width: 90%`, I've also tried `width: "90%" in case it would be looking for a string, but I got errors. How does this magic works?

Comment: I've tried percentages again as `width: 80%` and no error, but also no changes, what the heck?

Comment: I edited my comment with an example. Also, the resizeMode attribute is a style attribute for Image components, not View.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I still didn't solve it, if I use percentage on the top container it will resize the whole card, when I applied the style for the Image component the image disappears. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, you'll still need at least 3 components. Leave the card alone, have a View inside the card with the manual sizing, then have the Image inside the View the resizeMode attribute.